# When moving a file between drives, why does Windows 8.1 or Server 2012 R2 move the file twice?

Tags: windows-8.1, file-transfer, windows-server-2012-r2

It's happened to me before on Windows 8.1 and now on Server 2012 R2, but I'm trying to **move** a disconnected VHDX file from one drive to another. The move completed fine and progress bar completed to 100% but for some reason the progress bar shows up again straight after and starts the move process all over again. I'm afraid to stop it so I just let it go. its a 200gb file so it's a little annoying.

Comment: Does the target drive have a caching SSD accelerating the disks or something? If so, perhaps you have some old drivers/firmware.